# Websocket fails to connect

Tags: c#, .net-core, cryptography, x509certificate2

I have created websocket server and binded the self signed certificate with it , when websocket client fails to connect .
Eventviewer logs has this error.

"The TLS server credential's certificate does not have a private key information property attached to it. This most often occurs when a certificate is backed up incorrectly and then later restored. This message can also indicate a certificate enrollment failure."

Please find below code for creating self sign certificate.

```
var dn = new X500DistinguishedName("CN=" + Dns.GetHostName(), X500DistinguishedNameFlags.None);
var rsa = RSA.Create(); 
var req = new CertificateRequest(dn, rsa, HashAlgorithmName.SHA512, RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1);

// key usage: Digital Signature and Key Encipherment
req.CertificateExtensions.Add(new X509KeyUsageExtension(System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyUsageFlags.KeyEncipherment, true));

// Enhanced key usages
req.CertificateExtensions.Add(
                new X509EnhancedKeyUsageExtension(
                    new OidCollection {
                        new Oid("1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1")  // TLS Server auth
                    }, false));

req.CertificateExtensions.Add(new X509SubjectKeyIdentifierExtension(req.PublicKey, false));

cert = req.CreateSelfSigned(DateTimeOffset.Now, DateTimeOffset.Now.AddYears(1));
cert.FriendlyName = "Test";

string CertPath = Path.Combine(certPath, Guid.NewGuid() + ".pfx");
File.WriteAllBytes(CertPath, cert.Export(X509ContentType.Pfx, ""));
```

Comment: Are both your server and client running on the same machine?

Comment: Not sure if you can put a comment in the middle of a statement.

Comment: @Alan yes both are running on same machine